# R viewer off kilter and slow

Tags: r, rstudio, viewer

I'm trying to look at some data in RStudio using View(). Code is running smoothly, but for some reason the display looks kind of off. Column labels are a little off from the rest of the column. See image here or below: https://ibb.co/gTJFCj0

Scrolling is also incredibly slow. It takes close to 5 seconds for it to respond at all.

I'm new to R, so I have absolutely no clue where to even begin looking. I'm guessing it may be that RStudio is trying to display everything at once?

Comment: I have run into this glitch before, especially after filtering data via the View tab filters. It is only a display/graphical glitch,due to a large number of columns. Perhaps try something like head() instead of loading the entire data.frame into the Viewer? I'm unsure what you are looking for exactly, you have no question in this post

Comment: Added rstudio tag.